# Loop through array if it exists?

Tags: php

I have two arrays:

```
$qa_content['form']['fields']
$qa_content['form_q_edit']['fields']
```

One or zero of them exist at the same time at most. I want to loop through the one that exists.

I could do something like:

```
if isset($qa_content['form_q_edit']['fields']){
  loop($qa_content['form_q_edit']['fields'])
}elseif (isset $qa_content['form_q_edit']['fields']{
  loop($qa_content['form_q_edit']['fields'])
}
```

But is there a cleaner/smarter way of doing it, maybe by mergeing them or something?

Comment: Not sure if it makes any difference but you could use [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) instead of `isset()`. You'd use it like so: `array_key_exists('fields', $qa_content['form']);`...

Comment: @War10ck  Yes, there is multiple ways to solve a problem in software engineering.

Comment: @self Sorry, I'm a little confused by your comment? I'm aware there are multiple ways of solving this. I was more meaning I'm not sure if it will make any noticable difference in execution time, flow, etc.

Comment: Nope! There's no `cleaner/smarter` way.

Comment: Will there be more keys in `$qa_content` at the `'form_q_edit'` or `'form'` level???

Comment: 'Smarter' can lead confusing code and 'cleaner' can lead to unexpected results. Your current solution works and is easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

if the loop-function does the same for both arrays merge them and after that call the loop-function like this:

```
$merge= array_merge($qa_content['form_q_edit']['fields'], $qa_content['form_q_edit']['fields']);
if($all){
 loop($merge);
}
```

Comment: Is it cleaner/smarter for you?

Comment: in my opinion its a bit cleaner. A duplicated if-/elseif-clause is not that clean.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if the processing of the arrays would be the same.  If so the best optimization would be not to duplicate the more complex processing logic in the loop.  For example, if the processing in the loop would be the same it would be better to only have the loop processing logic once like:

```
$myArr = NULL;

if isset($qa_content['form_q_edit']['fields']){
  $myArr = $qa_content['form_q_edit']['fields'];
}elseif (isset $qa_content['form_q_edit']['fields']){
  $myArr = $qa_content['form_q_edit']['fields'];
}

if(!is_null($myArr))
{
  loop($myArr)
  {
    //do common processing here
  }
}
```